# Gradle wrapper credentials requirements

Tags: gradle, wrapper

I'm trying to get the credentials to work to download the gradle distribution. Currently, i've set the credentials in my root gradle.properties file like:

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=user
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=password
```

Now I know the credentials are correct because, in Intellij, if I click "reload all gradle projects", the distribution downloads from the new location without issue. I've tested this by also setting an invalid password and clicking "reload all gradle projects" and i get a 401 error. So thats all and well to know the credentials are correct.

The problem is if I go to my root project and run ./gradlew clean build, the distribution download fails with a 401 error. Why would the settings and credentials work when reloading the project through intellij but fail when trying to run the build in command line?